# vue v-for loop not reading json value

Tags: json, vue.js, youtube

I'm have a strange problem with Vue.

I'm sending it a youtube playlist json return. I'm trying to bind the URL of the thumbnail in a vfor loop, however, it keeps saying the value is undefined. However I'm logging the response in the console and it's defiantly there. Any idea what the issue is? here is my code: (the local host is just getting the youtube list with my API key. All values work EXCEPT for **item.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url** the error I get from vue is

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <br>
    Click Image To See Video
            <div v-for="item in playlist">
    <a :href="'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+item.snippet.resourceId.videoId">
  <img :src="item.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url" :alt="item.snippet.title">  
  </a>
  </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import videoLink from './components/videoLink.vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue';
const registered = [];

export default {
  name: 'app',
    data: () => ({
    loaded: false,
    playlist: [],
    errors: [],
  }),
 created() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:1234')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.items[0])      
        this.playlist = response.data.items;
        console.log(response.data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url)
        console.log(this.playlist)

        this.loaded = true;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        this.errors.push(e);
      });
  },
  components: {
    videoLink
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: chec if console.log(response.data.items[0]) giving proper value or not

Comment: It might be that one of the items in the list is missing that property. Did you verify that *all* the items have this property?

Comment: @Helpinghand yes it's showing up, it only doesn't work in the v-for loop

Comment: @JAM I used the "Default" property as well, same error.

Comment: Error is crystal clear: there is no maxres property in object item.snippet.thumbnails. Just read your json structure more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the first item in the array doesn't have a maxres property? The way I read the docs is that it's that the maxres could be available for some, but isn't a guarantee to be there.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails

There is a default object too so you could do a check if maxres available use it, and then fallback on default.

Comment: if i change it to default, low, medium, high or maxres the problem is the same. If I set the value to JSON.stringify(item.snippet.thumbnails) I get {"default":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y1zJn4hnS-Q/default.jpg","width":120,"height":90},"medium":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y1zJn4hnS-Q/mqdefault.jpg","width":320,"height":180},"high":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y1zJn4hnS-Q/hqdefault.jpg","width":48... continued, so it should be fine